# User profile. Should I create a new model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

this is basically a theoretical question. 
What do you think is better for a normal rails app with users:

1)Create a Profile model where to put resume, images, links etc...

2)Put all the data in the user model.

The first choice maybe is cleaner but you have to load 2 models from the db, so maybe slower.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

I normally have a single User model. If I have unrelated resources that may deserve an associated model, than I create one for them.

For example, for me the Resume (assuming is not a single field) may deserve a dedicated `Resume` model, with a one-to-one association to `User`.

On the view, I normally create an `/account` resource that internally displays the account and provides the `show`, `edit` and `update` actions to view the account or update it.

The more models you have, the more your architecture will become complicated. So unless you have the need to split the fields out of the User model, I would keep them inside the model.

When you start to have several fields that may require a prefix, such as `resume_title`, `resume_body`, `resume_created_at` inside the `User` model, that's a good indication that you probably need a separate `Resume` model associated to the `User`.

Comment: Then if I understand correctly finally you have 2 models with a one-to-one association, one for user and another one for resume. This is basically what I wanted to express in the second choice but also including some other information, not just the resume.